# How to correctly configure MongoDB to use Letsencrypt SSL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-14.04, tls, mongodb

How do I correctly configure MongoDB to use Letsencrypt SSL on Ubuntu?

I have created an SSL certificate using Letsencrypt and combined it via:

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem > /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

And setup mongo config like:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

But I get this error when trying to start Mongo:

```
No SSL certificate validation can be performed since no CA file has been provided; please specify an sslCAFile parameter
```

How do I correctly set the CAFile? Doesn't Ubuntu typically use a "CA Path" with a bunch of different root certs in their own files? I tried using the CURL CA bundle but that didn't work either.

Im using Mongo v3.0.12 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I would first try doing what the error message suggests.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But where/what CA File am I supposed to use? Doesn't Ubuntu typically use a "CA Path" with a bunch of different root certs in their own files? I tried using the CURL CA bundle but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 10):

You combine the wrong pem files. You need to combine `privkey.pem` with `cert.pem`.

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem > /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

For the CAFile you need to download IdenTrust DST Root CA X3 from https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html

```
sudo touch /etc/ssl/ca.crt
sudo chmod 777 /etc/ssl/ca.crt
```

Add the certificate of the website, add -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- lines and make sure you end with a new line saving the file:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssl/ca.crt
```

Then convert the crt file to a pem using:

```
sudo touch /etc/ssl/ca.pem
sudo chmod 777 /etc/ssl/ca.pem
sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/ca.crt -out /etc/ssl/ca.pem -outform PEM
```

And combine with `chain.pem` from Let's Encrypt into a single file `ca.pem`

```
sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem >> /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

To set the CAFile follow this mongo configuration setup:

```
net:  
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:  
    mode: requireSSL  
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

Restart MongoDB:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Don't forget the moment when you renew the Let's Encrypt certificates, you need to renew also `mongo.pem` and `ca.pem`.

Comment: Awesome answer! I can't thank you enough. Why did you use a CAFile from Identrust instead of Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/certificates)?

Comment: @RodrigoPedroso - Good question, don't know.

Comment: Because let's encrypt is quite new at that time, they are using Identrust to cross sign their certificates. You can download it directly from https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt. Now Let's encrypt is widely trusted

Comment: When combining with chain.pem, I'm getting an error : unable to get issuer certificate whereas if I use directly the Root certificate without combining it says it's ok. (When using openssl command to verify)

Comment: This is the command used to verify : openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/ca.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mongo0.example.com/mongodb.pem

Answer (score 3):

The CA file you need can be obtained from Letsencrypt, look for one of the intermediate certificates here:

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Then, specify the path to that certificate with the [SSL CAFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.CAFile) option.

Answer (score 1):

mongod needs the whole certificate chain including intermediaries and crucially, the **root ca**.
for whatever reason, certbot does not include the root ca on your filesystem when it obtains or renews a cert so you must do a little work to establish the root ca (it can change over time, depending on normal cert expiries or extraordinary revocations).

on may 5th, 2023, a valid mechanism for determining the root ca is as follows:

- give your host a fully qualified domain name for a domain that you control (make sure to update dns to resolve the name to your host):

  ```shell
  sudo hostnamectl set-hostname alpha.example.com
  ```
- obtain a let's encrypt cert with certbot. supply a post-hook argument to ensure you get a copy of the cert in the format mongod requires (private_key+cert+intermediaries) and that the copy stays up to date when certbot renews your cert in the future:

  ```shell
  sudo certbot certonly \
    --noninteractive \
    --cert-name $(hostname -f) \
    --key-type ecdsa \
    --force-renewal \
    --post-hook "cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/$(hostname -f)/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/$(hostname -f)/fullchain.pem > /etc/ssl/$(hostname -f).pem" \
    --expand \
    --allow-subset-of-names \
    -m ops@example.com \
    --agree-tos \
    --no-eff-email \
    --preferred-challenges http \
    --standalone \
    -d $(hostname -f)
  ```
- split the fullchain.pem file obtained by certbot into separate temporary files for each cert that it contains:

  ```shell
  sudo csplit \
    --prefix /tmp/cert \
    --elide-empty-files \
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/$(hostname -f)/fullchain.pem \
    '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/' \
    '{*}'
  ```
- determine the root ca by examining the cert and intermediaries:

  ```shell
  for cert in /tmp/cert*; do
    echo ${cert}
    openssl \
      x509 \
      -in ${cert} \
      -inform PEM \
      -subject \
      -issuer \
      -nameopt RFC2253 \
      -fingerprint \
      -noout
    echo
  done
  ```

  output might look like this (your first block, will definitely be different):

  ```
  /tmp/cert00
  subject=CN=alpha.example.com
  issuer=CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
  SHA1 Fingerprint=60:50:DE:3E:FA:F1:DF:30:3F:1B:73:F0:1B:F4:44:51:92:C5:CB:0D

  /tmp/cert01
  subject=CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
  issuer=CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US
  SHA1 Fingerprint=A0:53:37:5B:FE:84:E8:B7:48:78:2C:7C:EE:15:82:7A:6A:F5:A4:05

  /tmp/cert02
  subject=CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US
  issuer=CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.
  SHA1 Fingerprint=93:3C:6D:DE:E9:5C:9C:41:A4:0F:9F:50:49:3D:82:BE:03:AD:87:BF
  ```

  the example output shows the subject and issuer for each cert extracted from fullchain.pem
  it shows the issuer for each cert in the chain, except the final one, the root CA:

  - `CN=alpha.example.com` was issued by `CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US`
  - `CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US` was issued by `CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US`
  - `CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US` was issued by `CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.`
- the final issuer (`CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.`) cert is missing from the filesystem, but that's ok, we know the sha fingerprint of a cert it issued (`933C6DDEE95C9C41A40F9F50493D82BE03AD87BF` with colons removed) and we can [look that up on censys](https://search.censys.io/certificates-legacy?resource=certificates-legacy&q=933C6DDEE95C9C41A40F9F50493D82BE03AD87BF), who provide a link to the issuer (`DST Root CA X3`) cert and its [pem file](https://search.censys.io/certificates-legacy/2686e09f42a52571627f4a90b9a89f68d20e8e019718b100e3de7413d5e61647/pem):

  ```
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/
  MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
  DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTI0MDkzMDE4MTQwM1ow
  PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD
  Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
  AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O
  rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq
  OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b
  xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw
  7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD
  aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV
  HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG
  SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69
  ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr
  AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz
  R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5
  JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo
  Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  ```

  once you have the pem file on your filesystem, you can add a `CAFile` entry to your mongod.conf and restart your mongod.service which should make mongo and it's cluster peers happy.

Comment: Is there no other way to generate the CA File from lets encrypt ? When I try to use one of the root certificate of letsencrypt, I'm getting "error 2 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate"

Comment: as of today, let's encrypt does not publish the root ca cert. as far as i am aware they have never published it. let's encrypt's root ca (DST Root CA X3) is a self signed cert that is not trusted by any mainstream default os configuration that i know of and is explicitly distrusted by some CA's. it's not a good state of affairs but the internet would be broken if nobody trusted let's encrypt regardless.

Comment: So basically you can only use the same root you found using the steps you describe, no other root will work right ?

Comment: if the issuer sig for the top intermediary in your chain is 933C6DDEE95C9C41A40F9F50493D82BE03AD87BF, then yes. however let's encrypt do use some other intermediary chains and i believe the current default intermediary chain is not going to live forever. at some point let's encrypt will fix the silly current state of affairs.